# Where to find modern Romantic style piano composers?

Tags: classical-music, chopin

I've noticed some things I didn't quite get right in my first request.

I was being too restrictive, I wasn't looking for modern composers in particular, just ones that composed in the style I liked.

I don't think I'm very good at explaining, so I'll let my example do all the talking for me. All I'm looking for are pieces of music that are like these examples. I've embedded timestamps into the URLs as well.

Please take the time to listen to at least a bit of each of the above links, they really explain what I'm after.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try searching for "neoromantic", or variations on it. For example a [YouTube search for "neo romanticism music piano"](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=neo%20romanticism%20music%20piano) turned up (among others):

- ["Changes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9STj0rb-40), by Pam Wedgewood
- ["Neo Romanticism"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_jpXXUhC8w), by Matthew S. Anderson
- ["Etude Of Madness"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x5u4W35QhU), by Taki
- ["Nocturne in D-Flat Major"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yT-B5DkN_2g), by WickedProductions100

Wikipedia's entry for ["Neoromanticism (music)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoromanticism_(music)) lists a number of composers considered neoromantic, such as:

- Wolfgang Rihm (["Klavierstück Nr. 5"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IafNWn7LUg0))
- David Del Tredici (["Virtuoso Alice"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvUFVOmpv8M))
- Ellen Taaffe Zwilich (["Lament"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luA1V_c6WpQ))

Comment: Hi, I realised my question didn't really cover what  I was looking for. I've updated it. Could you check out the new question? Thanks